# How can I export a Laradock project to be installed in another machine with no internet?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laradock

How can I export a [Laradock](https://laradock.io/) project to be installed in another machine with no internet?

I've tried the `docker save` command but no luck yet, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer, this is the command I had to run:

```
docker save -o server.tar laradock_nginx laradock_php-fpm laradock_workspace laradock_mysql docker:19.03-dind
```

The way I got those imagines names is by booting up Laradock and the checking the active images with the command `docker ps`

Then on the computer with no internet, I loaded the server.tar with this command `docker load -i server.tar`

Next, I went to the Laradock folder inside my Laravel project and run `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql` and it worked like a charm.